# Match an int value to a text tag

Tags: java, android

How do I match an int value to a Tag? For example, when seting the visibility of a view, VISIBLE actually return 2, GONE returns 0, etc

How can I do this so I can make my code more easily to read?

Comment: Please provide code showing that you have at least attempted to solve this alone, and we will help you from there.

Comment: It is recommended to use the VISIBLE name within the code.  So you can use "View.VISIBLE" and "View.GONE" wherever possible.  Using 0 and 2 would be considered an abstraction violation.  Best to pretend you don't even know about the 0 and 2 values.

Comment: @FishStix This was really just an example, what I want is to create my own tag with my own int values

Comment: within a class, you can declare "public static final int VISIBLE = 2"

Comment: You could also use an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final int TAG_NAME = 3
```

Another thing to consider might be to use an enum.  This can minimize incorrect use of tags.  e.g. Expecting one of three tags which equal 0, 1, and 2; but a user passes in 3.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you basically want it to be so that you can replace a number with a constant "tag" or name.  Just make a variable.  Use (`visibility`) (`static`) (`final`) type `name = initial_Value;` for example:

```
public static final int GONE = 0;
```

If you want it to be an instance variable and not global, don't add `static` (and probably not `public` either).  Final makes it a constant, so if you want to change it later don't add that, but since you are trying to make a "tag" you probably want it to be constant.